# Does a free piston mean the process is isobaric, even when the piston is not massless?

Tags: thermodynamics

If the piston is massless, the net force acting must be zero, so the pressure exerted by gas is constant and equal to the atmospheric pressure, provided there is no other external force. But what if the piston has some mass, it's free to move? Can't it accelerate making the force on the two sides unequal resulting to a variable pressure by gas? My teacher said it is isobaric, so i'm kinda confused.

Comment: Is it your understanding that the piston come to rest in the final thermodynamic equilibrium state?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the details of the problem (which are, admittedly, not always clearly stated). For example:

- Some problems with massive pistons deal with a static situation, where the mass of the piston adds to the atmospheric pressure. In this case one does not ask how the piston moved and how the system arrived to its current state, as long as it is in equilibrium.
- In problems with moving pistons one often assumes that there is an external force that prevents the piston from accelerating. Another variation is with assumption that the friction prevents the piston from accelerating. This latter is problematic, as the friction means energy dissipation, i.e., loss of the energy of the gas. However, in some cases such losses could be neglected - it depends on the mass of the piston and the magntitude of the friction force.
- Finally, even when the piston accelerates, but its maximum velocity is not too high, one can still treat the gas expansion/comoression as quasistatic - oen can think of interesting problems here - e.g., oscillations of piston after its release.

Answer (score 0):

The piston-gas system (mass of piston not zero) would remain isobaric if the process remains reversible or quasi-static. This means that the piston moves very slowly such that we can approximate the acceleration to be zero.

Further $W=P_{\text{external}}\Delta V$, where $P_{\text{ext}}=\frac{mg}{A}+P_{\text{atm}}$. Your teacher possibly assumed the thermodynamic process to be reversible beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If the piston comes to rest in the final equilibrium state, then any kinetic energy that was imparted to the piston during the process is ultimately dissipated within the gas.  So, in the end, the net amount of work done by the gas on the piston turns out the same as if the piston were massless.  So, in the end, your teacher was right, but he or she should have presented more details on why this is so, including an energy balance on the piston:  $$W_{g,p}(t)-W_{p,a}(t)=K(t)$$ where $W_{g,p}(t)$ is the work done by the gas on the piston up to time t, $W_{p,a}(t)$ is the work done by the piston on the outside atmosphere up to time t, and K(t) is the kinetic energy of the piston at time t.  At infinite time, when the piston comes to rest, we have:  $$W_{g,p}(\infty)-W_{p,a}(\infty)=0$$or$$W_{g,p}(\infty)=W_{p,a}(\infty)=P_{atm}\Delta V$$